# Using TDD: File Synchronization with Client/Server

Tags: java, tdd, client-server

I started trying to learn tdd and wanted to use it on a real project. So I decided on programming a simple file synchronization with a client and a server in java. 
After more or less finishing the client part, I got stuck while writing the server part.

In order to unit test the logic without accessing external resources, I put those in separate classes, so that I could mock them. So far, so good.

Now here's my question:

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAKpX.jpg) shows how I imagined everything could look like, where green parts are finished and the yellow parts are not yet implemented.

In my case I'd have to pass `RemoteServer` a `ConnectionManager`. The `ConnectionManager` would a need a `FileAdapter` and a `Communicator` in order to create a `ClientConnectionHandler`. That sounds like a little bit too much passing for me. Is this normal for tdd'ing or am I doing something wrong in order to keep everything testable?

edit: The class ClientConnectionHandler is only responsible for the file sync logic on the server side, which means: Following my own mini protocol to receive files from a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty normal. If you get one class that has many dependencies, it likely has [too many responsibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as well. But having one class that depends on another class that depends on another - that's normal.

This is why [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) Container libraries like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) are popular. They make it easier to wire up (configure and resolve) all of the dependencies.

Comment: +1 spot on about too many responsibilities (client connection handler might actually need a small hierarchy of classes -- 1 base class and two derived classes -- tho it's hard to tell what it actually does from the diagram).  And IoC container library is a good solution for the chained-down dependencies issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I will have a look at Spring. About having too many responsibilities: I already tried to follow the SRP. The class `ClientConnectionHandler` is only responsible for the file sync logic on the server side, which means: Following my own mini protocol to receive files from a client. I couldn't think of a way to split it up into several different classes. Any hints, maybe?

Comment: @b1nh: so it converts from the network to a file (or vice-versa)?  You probably want an interem representation (stream/event-based stream abstraction if you don't want or have a use for an in-memory object model - kind of like XML readers) to avoid violating SRP.  Holding onto or working with connections + files at the same time is too big a responsibility for one class, IMO.

Comment: @Merlyn: The connection handler itself delegates file access to the `FileSystemAdapter` and network communication to `SocketCommunicator` so receiving a file in the handler might look like `fileadapter.writeToFile(communicator.getbytes,filename)`. I thought this way I'd not violate SRP.

Comment: @b1nh: That sounds good then.  I'd have to see the code to tell you for sure, but you probably don't need to split it up.  Btw, if this answer helped you (I think it is a good answer), I'd mark it as accepted.  Gives points to TrueWill :)